# PHP submit button causes strang url issue

Tags: php, submit

I am working on a PHP search box, it's supposed to work specifically with a database to find keywords. When I click the search button though the only thing that changes is the URL, I have looked over the code a dozen times and can't seem to find the error. I thought it has to be in my name "searchSubmitButton", but I have made absolutely sure that correct everywhere. I have found as well a few other spelling errors, but I'm sure there must be one I'm missing.

[Here is an imgur that shows what happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVEiG.jpg) as you can see the url changes, but nothing else prints as it should.

EDIT: I'm so sorry I absent minded forgot to post my code.

index.php

```
<?php

require("./config.php");

if (isset($_POST['searchSubmitButton'])) { // If the form has been submitted
    if (!isset($_POST['searchText']) || empty($_POST['searchText'])) { //If the search text wasn't set
        die("<strong>Error:</strong> Search text empty");
    } else {
        $searchText = $mysql->real_escape_string($_POST['searchText']);

        $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `product` LIKE '%" . $searchText . "%'");

        if ($query->num_rows) { // If at least one row has been returned
            print("<h3>Results:</h3>\n");
            print("<table id=\"resultsTable\">\n");

            print("<th>Item Number</th>\n");
            print("<th>Product</th>\n");
            print("<th>Price</th>\n");

            while ($product = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
                print("<tr>\n");

                print("<td>" . $product['id'] . "</td>\n");
                print("<td>" . $product['product'] . "</td>\n");
                print("<td>" . $product['price'] . "</td>\n");

                print("</tr>\n");
            }
            print ("</table>\n");
        } else { // If nothing has been returned
            print("<h3>Sorry, there were no products matching your search.</h3>\n");
        }
    }
}

print("<h2>Search Products</h2>\n");
print("<form id=\"searchForm\" action=\"./\" methond=\"post\">\n");
print("<input id=\"searchText\" name\"searchText\" type=\"text\" /><br /><br />\n");
print("<button id=\"searchSubmitButton\" name=\"searchSubmitButton\" type=\"submit\">Search</button>\n");
print("</form>")
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php

$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUser = "root";
$dbPass = "";
$dbName = "test1";

$mysql = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);

if ($mysql->connect_error) {
    die("<strong>Error: </strong> (" . $mysql->connect_errno . ")" . $mysql->connect_error);
} else {
    print("<strong>Successfully connected to the database.</strong><br /><br />");
}
?>
```

Comment: Please give us some code. HTML & PHP

Comment: Place your code here cant identify problem unless until code is provided

Comment: Just an assumption of your code from what you have said, if you are looking for `$_POST` variables in your PHP you wont find them because your form is sending a GET request. If you want to use POST in your back-end PHP then you need your form to send that by using `method="POST"` in your open `<form>` tag.

Comment: Would like to see the HTML.......

Comment: Here's your problem `methond=\"post\"` typo `n` - change to `method=\"post\"` that should fix 'er right up. ;-)

Comment: That typo almost got it, not it's throwing back the error message even when I type something in the search box.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if you're not already doing so, and give us the exact error message it's throwing back.

Comment: I don't have a syntax error, I think it's just a logic error, I did add the code, but nothing came back as an error.

Comment: Try changing `action=\"./\"` to `action=\"\"` or `action=''` as I take it that you want to perform the action from inside the same page, correct?

Comment: No I keep getting the same thing, it's not posting results like it should in a table, it's just posting my Error: Search text empty as if I didn't type anything.

Comment: Try changing `if($query->num_rows)` to `if($query->num_rows() > 0)` I think that's what the issue here is.

Comment: Nope, still not working for some reason

Comment: Now I know I found your problem. Ok, scrap my comment about `if($query->num_rows)` to `if($query->num_rows() > 0)` that'll throw an error. The problem is here `name\"searchText\"` the equal sign is missing. Change to `name=\"searchText\"` and it will work; I've tested it now. That's why it did not work and you got that message every time.

Comment: HAHA! YEAH! IT WORKED, No idea how happy I am to see that. I swear after I look over my code for a few hours it just all stats running together. Thank you for your hard work in helping find these errors.

Comment: You're very much welcome. I'd put in an answer, but I've sworn to myself I wouldn't anymore. Too many idiots downvoting perfectly good answers these days. Just don't accept the one given below hahaha

Comment: I think the main issue with code like that, is the `\"` escaped quotes, that are hard to spot probable missing equal signs.

Comment: However, in this instance, I'm almost tempted to put in an answer for you to mark as resolved. Call it my "coming out of retirement" answer ;-)

Comment: Right on. Glad to have been able to help and have made your day, *cheers!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems that are causing your code to fail are these:

```
methond=\"post\"
```

which contains a typo. Change it to:

```
method=\"post\"
```

Also, a missing equal sign in

```
name\"searchText\"
```

change it to

```
name=\"searchText\"
```

and your code will work.

Sidenote: You may also want to change `action=\"./\"` to `action=\"\"` or `action=''` given you're executing everything from the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mistaking **GET** and **POST** requests. What you have now is a **GET** request, which means the data you submit through the form will be appended to the url. What you want is a post request (data does not get appended to url and gets directly sent to the php page). Just change `method="get"` to `method="post"` in your form tag.

To answer the edited question with code: The code you're using now is waiting for a **POST** request but your form is sending a **GET** request, as said add `method="post"` to your `<form>`, submit the form and php will recognize it.

I'd suggest you to read [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)